# RDD to in.file to external process to out.file to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, amazon-emr

I need to call an external process from my EMR Spark job. I see that `rdd.pipe` would allow me to pipe an RDD to a process. (As an aside, is that one process per RDD, or one per element?).

However, my external process requires a filename as input and generates a file as output.

How can I invoke this external process and subsequently load the output file as an RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that one process per RDD, or one per element?

Neither. It is a process per partition.

> process requires a filename as input and generates a file as output. How can

The simplest solution is to write a simple wrapper which writes to randomly generated path, invokes your program, reads the file and writes to stdout and this is pretty much all what `pipe` is about. Unless you write to distributed file system you wouldn't be able to retriever the output otherwise.